# How can I Get an original/parent object value in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have 3, Vector3 positions defined, at the initialization of my code.

```
Vector3 A = new Vector3(377.999f, 326.656f, 103.566f);
Vector3 B = new Vector3(1137.728f, -981.551f, 46.416f);
Vector3 C = new Vector3(-1223.76f, -905.604f, 12.326f);
```

Then I have float objects for each Vector3 defined above.

```
   float Store_distance1 = World.GetDistance(my.Position, A); //Distance from my.pos to A
   float Store_distance2 = World.GetDistance(my.Position, B); //Distance from my.pos to B
   float Store_distance3 = World.GetDistance(my.Position, C); //Distance from my.pos to C
```

Now, when calling it, in a method, I have defined as below.

```
private void SelectNearestStore()
    {
             List<float> NearestStore = new List <float>
             {
                 Store_distance1, Store_distance2, Store_distance3           
             };

              for (int i = 0; i < NearestStore.Count; i++)
                 {
                     if (NearestStore.Min() == NearestStore[i])
                      {
                        Console.write("Nearest Store is " + NearestStore[i].ToString() + " Meters Away");

                        Console.write("Location of the Store is " + //Vector3 property of A or B or C)
                      }

                 }

    }
```

Let's say, Store_distance2 is the lowest value among all,

In which case, I am getting the correct float point in for loop at first console.writeline().

How can I get the B value to display at second console writeline()?

Comment: Consider creating an object for your stores. Add them a method which computes the distance property (given the current position as an argument). Then you can iterate over your stores instead of over a list of detached floats. Also, your solution will become hard to maintain as soon as the number of stores increases, because you statically combine that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Dictionary<Vector3, float>` which holds the vector and its distance to your position:

```
var map = new Dictionary<Vector3, float>();
map[A] = World.GetDistance(my.Position, A); //Distance from my.pos to A
map[B] = World.GetDistance(my.Position, B); //Distance from my.pos to B
map[C] = World.GetDistance(my.Position, C); //Distance from my.pos to C
```

Now you can easily print every vector together with its distance:

```
var min = map.Min(x => x.Value);
foreach(var kv in map)
{
    if (kv.Value == min)
    {
        Console.write("Nearest Store is " + min + " Meters Away");   
        Console.write("Location of the Store is " + kv.Key.ToString();
    }
}
```

The last `Console.WriteLine` surely assumes that `ToString` is overriden on `Vector3`, which I´m not sure about.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much crisp answer and an explanation.!